# Why won't Azure AD B2C accept an Office 365 email address?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

The sample web application is using Azure AD B2C for identity and authentication. Azure AD B2C has been configured with Microsoft as an identity provider. Azure AD B2C will login a user with a personal Microsoft account, but not an Office 365 account with a custom domain name. This is also the email address for the Azure admin, and is even the only user under `Home > Azure AD B2C > Users - All users`. The email address was under `Users` by default when the Azure AD B2C resource was created.

Why can't this email address be used to login?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, why can't O365 users login, it's because configuring "Microsoft authentication" only allows personal MS accounts. 
To allow O365, you'd need to configure B2C to allow login via Azure AD.

As for why your admin user can't login, it's because there are different types of users in B2C.
Your admin is not a B2C user, and thus cannot login as a local user.
It's confusing since the Users tab shows them all together :/